# Can select statement also inquiry rows aside from columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

My code worked but I don't know why!

Isn't NAME a row and not a column. So why the select statement worked?

```
SELECT NAME FROM CITY WHERE COUNTRYCODE='JPN';
```

Comment: NAME and COUNTRYCODE are both columns in the structure you have been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows don't have names. The City table as shown is not how the data table actually "looks". They are using a grid so that they could show you the name and types of the fields, and the fields are columns. If you queried the table with a SELECT *, it would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only SELECT using column names. NAME, in this case is a column name.